# Extracting Current line if some sub-string match first time only?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string like this

```
str = ["asap subject ssfs sfdsf sdfsdfsdefs sdfssdf","nsubject qwerty 
        swqt","dsfsdf sdfsdf sdfsfs sfsdf er:subject adsdsd dsdfs 
       sdfsdfsdfsds"]
```

What i Want

```
str = ["ssfs sfdsf sdfsdfsdefs sdfssdf","qwerty 
        swqt","adsdsd dsdfs sdfsdfsdfsds"]
```

I using

```
for i in range(0,len(str)):
      list_i.append(str[i].strip("subject*)[1])
```

But problem is when i have long text after subject and i want value of current line only.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking: the match between what?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be using the str.split function.

Instead of

```
str[i].strip("subject")[1]
```

replace that with

```
str[i].split("subject ",1)[-1]
```

This splits the string at "subject", then takes the last element of that result.